# Android multiple recycle views in single activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, tableview

I am facing a design challenge, I want to design a layout for an app that is showing data in form of table with 1st leftmost column fixed (not changed), the rightmost 2 column can be changed when user presses next button. My initial approach is to use 2 recycle views, one vertical and horizontals. Since i get company names in one arraylist (which is horizontally displayed). Leftmost column in one arraylist which is vertical, and the rest of data in one arraylist, the data is displayed in rows. Then on next button click repopulates recycleview with next set of elements from table, the data is in the form of **matrix**. To show visually what i want to achieve i have designed a mockup. If anyone has an idea of what will be the best approach to achieve this layout design, i highly appreciate it.

[image]

```
public class TableViewActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerViewGames, recyclerViewOdds;
    private CustomAdapterGames adapterGames;
    private CustomAdapterOdds adapterOdds;

    private ArrayList<String> stringList;

    private int draggingView = -1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_table_view_2);

        AppBarHelper.setAppBarText(this, R.string.title_activity_table_view);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        recyclerViewGames = findViewById(R.id.table_view_recycle_view_games);
        recyclerViewOdds = findViewById(R.id.table_view_recycle_view_odds);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager2 = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);

        recyclerViewGames.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerViewOdds.setLayoutManager(layoutManager2);

        stringList = new ArrayList<>();

        stringList.add("dummy");
        stringList.add("dummy");
        stringList.add("dummy");
        stringList.add("dummy");
        stringList.add("dummy");

        adapterGames = new CustomAdapterGames(this, stringList);
        adapterOdds = new CustomAdapterOdds(this, stringList);



        recyclerViewGames.setAdapter(adapterGames);
        recyclerViewOdds.setAdapter(adapterOdds);

        recyclerViewGames.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
        recyclerViewOdds.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
    }

    private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener scrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if (recyclerViewGames == recyclerView && newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                draggingView = 1;
            } else if (recyclerViewOdds == recyclerView && newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                draggingView = 2;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (draggingView == 1 && recyclerView == recyclerViewGames) {
                recyclerViewOdds.scrollBy(dx, dy);
            } else if (draggingView == 2 && recyclerView == recyclerViewOdds) {
                recyclerViewGames.scrollBy(dx, dy);
            }
        }
    };


}
```

The issue i am facing is that two recycleviews scroll independently sometimes even though i have tried to make them scroll at same time.

Comment: the numbers in column c and d are dependent on the choice in the left column ?

Comment: A solution could be that you use only one RecyclerView with `GridLayoutManager` and arrange your adapter items column wise => header1,header2,header3,item11,item12,item13, etc.

Comment: @LenaBru No it's basically a comparison table, the user can compare values from different companies, those are not dependent.

Comment: Try to look it with a certain perspective that you can see only 1 RecyclerView needed to generate that list. If you can see it, you get what I mean. Because if you use more than 1 RecyclerView, you will have 3 scrollbars each which will ruin your design.

Comment: I understand and i want to avoid design issues, i am trying to design it following design standards. @harrytmthy

Comment: @AmirDora  I think you should post how the data you receive would look like. From what you said it seems you know how to create the recyclerviews but are unable to manage your data. Like @LenaBru suggested set your recyclerviews inside ```NestedScrollView``` and for each Header you get, use the position to get the corresponding item from the values list and add this to a new List, which you can then use to populate the last two vertical recyclerviews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the basic concept, it is up to you to set the layouts/models and other logic as needed good luck!

[Github POC](https://github.com/pikaboo/ThreeJollyRecyclerViews)

[image]

Comment: thanks for your solution, however for the first fixed column data is in column so a vertical column is ok. for 2nd-10th column it is row-wise. so in this case for the very first block "item1, item2, item3" data fetched for this row in this case data would be "1.1", "2.4" "2.6" and "6" (you can see in gif image).

Comment: i dont understand your column, please rephrase. I thought your issue was synchronizing the scroll between the items. It is up to you to put the correct data in it

Comment: thanks Lena, my approach was to use recycleview and somehow convert one to horizontal and use one vertically. I was experimenting. The thing is that I get data in rows and columns from API call request, in this case i get header in one arraylist, and leftmost column in one arraylist. The rest i get in one arraylist. The data is in form of matrix. I hope it's clear now

Comment: i did not see anything horizontal in your gif, the click is "notifyDataSetChanged"

Comment: Yes in gif it appears to be vertical but the problem is data is coming in seperate arraylist, if i want to populate in vertical recycleviews it is not possible. I have to use one vertical recycleview and one gridlayout maybe?! , but still not sure if that will work. your solution helped, i will have to modify it to suit my purpose. I am working on it.

Comment: I was able to achieve what i wanted to do and your code helped. Thanks :)